# AWS EC2 LifeCyle Hook vs User Data in Launch configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

In AWS EC2, both lifecycle hook and user data of launch configuration permits to execute some customised actions while launching instances.

Could you tell me is Lifecyle hook related actions are executed before or User data defined in launch configuration executed before ?

When do you chose which one ? What are their differences ?

Answer (score 4):

**User Data and Cloud-Init**

When launching an Amazon EC2 instance, you can provide a **User Data** field. The information entered in this field is available to the instance via `http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data/`.

This is an excellent way to **pass information to the instance** that is accessible to software running on the instance.

Then Canonical, maker of Ubuntu, [conceived](https://www.hashicorp.com/resources/cloudinit-the-good-parts) **Cloud-Init** as a way of running scripts during the startup of virtual machines. Cloud-Init takes a script passed via EC2 User Data and runs it as `root` during the first boot of an instance. It is a great way to **install software and configure the machine** when it is first used.

**Amazon EC2 Auto-Scaling Lifecycle Hooks**

Amazon EC2 Auto-Scaling is a method of automatically scaling a fleet of EC2 instances based on workload. Instances are **launched** or **terminated** based on a target capacity metric. Instances launched through Auto-Scaling are normal EC2 instances, so User Data can be used to configure these instances.

Sometimes, however, a more complex operation is required when launching/terminating instances. For example, when launching instances it might be necessary to contact an external configuration service, and when terminating instances it might be necessary to copy data off an instance. These tasks can be accomplished via **Lifecycle Hooks**.

From [Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling Lifecycle Hooks - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html):

> Lifecycle hooks enable you to perform custom actions by pausing instances as an Auto Scaling group launches or terminates them. When an instance is paused, it remains in a wait state until either you complete the lifecycle action using the complete-lifecycle-action CLI command or CompleteLifecycleAction API action, or the timeout period ends (one hour by default).

Compared to User Data, Lifecycle Hooks are rarely used. They are typically required when a longer-running or external process is required before instances are ready to process requests. For example, there might be a long startup process required for new instances that exceeds the time normally allowed for health checks. Or, an external process (outside the instance) might need to be triggered before the instance can start processing traffic.

Lifecycle Hooks are more complicated because they involve a signalling mechanism. When an Auto Scaling instance is launched or terminated, Auto Scaling will send a message via Amazon SQS or Amazon SNS. You are then responsible for running a process that responds to this signal. When the process is complete, it must send a signal back to Auto Scaling so that the instance can be fully added to, or removed from, the Auto Scaling group. This will typically require something running *external to the EC2 instance* to process the Lifecycle Hook.

**Bottom line:** You want to use User Data. It is rare that you would use a Lifecycle Hook.

Comment: Thanks John for the reply. So how about the question: the order of the execution of each one ? Imaging that, I have a script with user data, and also have Lifecycle  Hook for launching, which one will be execute first ?

Comment: When Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling launches a new instance, the instance is launched just like normal. The User Data script will execute on the instance when it starts up. This is _totally independent_ from the Lifecycle hook. Auto scaling will put the instance into an Auto Scaling "wait state" (this is just a status, it does not impact the instance itself), so it will not be added to a Load Balancer. Auto Scaling will wait until it receives a signal before putting the instance into the group and sending traffic (or, if no signal is received after one hour, it will put it in the group anyway).

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein please, how to send the signal of complete-lifecycle

Comment: @Hamza You can use the AWS CLI or an AWS SDK to send the signal (eg [complete-lifecycle-action — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/complete-lifecycle-action.html)).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your answers.
Actually, the LifeCycle hook is somehow useful. For example, in my situation, I have to deactivate Tableau Server licenses before the instance is terminated. This is a good situation to use it.

While, during starting up, user data is executed but the instance will be put into "In Service" states once the OS itself is up, even the user data is still not yet finished to be executed.

So to choose between the two approches, it all depends on what you want to do in the scripts.

Comment: This related [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html) is helpful and mentions that you can use the metadata to get the instance Id to invoke the **aws autoscaling complete-lifecycle-action**.